# Setting height of div

Tags: css

If I have:

```
body, html {
  height: 100%;
}

innerDiv {
  height: 100%;
}
```

is the height of `innerDiv` = height of view port, namely the window?

... or is the height = height of all the window’s content, which may be very tall, that is, way below the window’s bottom edge?

I know I could just use `100vh`, but I wish to avoid viewport units totally.

Comment: yes the viewport, if you have more content you will get an overflow

Comment: Just out of curiosity, why do you wish to avoid viewport totally?

Answer (score 0):

height=100% mean that the element should of that % in the parent element.
So here, If you have just a innerDiv in the html, the 100% would be just the innerDiv element. It wraps around it.

Tip: Always use border to try out the styles so that you are sure of what's happening.